# I want to find the centre of a circle, in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

What is the radius and center of the circle with equation

$$\left|\frac{z + (-2)}{z + (3)}\right| = 3$$

find the $(x,y)$ coordinates
and the value of the radius.

btw $z$ is a complex number

Comment: Probably the reason for the votes to close the question is that questions should not be phrased in language suitable for assigning homework. It can make people wonder if someone just copied a question without understanding what is asked.  You can ask for help understanding an assigned question, or you can posted an assigned problem and ask your own questions about it, but merely copying and doing nothing else is considered deficient.  People voting to close or down-voting a newbie's question for that reason ought to explain all that in comments, but usually they don't. $\qquad$

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to tackle the question as I don't know where to start.

Comment: One way would be to write $z=x+iy$, where $x$ and $y$ are real, then recall how to divide complex numbers, getting a quadratic equation in the two variables $x$ and $y$.  Then you will probably need to complete the square in both variables. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you know complex numbers, co-ordinate geometry and circles, I am writng the following solution:

$$\left|\frac{z + (-2)}{z + (3)}\right| = 3$$
or,$$\left|\frac{x+iy + (-2)}{x+iy + (3)}\right| = 3$$
or,$$\left|\frac{(x-2)+iy}{(x+3)+iy}\right| = 3$$
or,$$\frac{\left|(x-2)+iy\right|}{\left|(x+3)+iy\right|} = 3$$
or,$$\frac{\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{(x+3)^2+y^2}} = 3$$
or,$$\frac{(x-2)^2+y^2}{(x+3)^2+y^2} = 3^2$$
or,$$(x-2)^2+y^2 = 9(x+3)^2+9y^2$$
or,$$x^2+y^2-4x+4 = 9(x^2+6x+9)+9y^2$$
or,$$x^2+y^2-4x+4 = 9x^2+54x+81+9y^2$$
or,$$8x^2+8y^2+58x+77=0$$
or,$$x^2+y^2-2\cdot(-\frac{29}{8})x-2\cdot 0 y+\frac{77}{8}=0$$

So, centre $=(\frac{29}{8},0)$ 
and radius $=\sqrt{(\frac{29}{8})^2+(0)^2-\frac{77}{8}}=1.875$ unit